# XML Uniqueness and Reference

Tags: xml, xpath, reference, schema, unique

I have a strange situation in my XML Schema, I need to represent some data, for example an element called `element` that can have 3 attribute `att1`,`att2`,`att3` and the three must be unique as group.

This works fine with the declaration on a `<unique>` constraint, with three `field` and `xpath="attrN"`.

But I need also to point at the value of `attr1` in other element and is not needed to be unique as standing alone.

**example**: I would to have this:

```
<element att1="A" att2="B" att3="C" />
<element att1="A" att2="D" att3="C" />

<element att1="A" att2="B" att3="E" />
<element att1="K" att2="B" att3="F" />
```

It works until here... but also to have **in the same document**...

```
<element att1="A"/>
<element att1="K"/>
```

I can't do this with a `key` on `att1` because otherwise the first part of code will be not valid not even with `unique` declaration of `att1`.

How can I do this in XML Schema (with references)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution using `key` and `key_ref` for `elements` and not for `attributes`.